# Local Storage With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store a string locally so when the user reloads the page it saves what was last there.

I looked at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and tried to implement it.

I had this code which basicllay has a button and a dropdown list of colors to change the background.

When I close and reopen the doc I want it to be the color that I saved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>  

        </head>

        <body>
            <form action="">
                <label>
                    <select id="color">
                        <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
                        <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
                        <option value="#FFCC00">Orange</option>
                        <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
                        <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
                        <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
                        <option value="#663366">Indigo</option>
                        <option value="#FF00FF">Violet</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <input type="button" onClick="inputForm()" value="change color"/>
            <form>

            <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--
                function inputForm(){
                    var color = document.getElementById("color");

                    var outputContents=color.value;

                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = outputContents;
                }
            //-->
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I made this code to do that but it didn't work

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>

    <body onload="storeColor()">
        <form action="">
            <label>
                <select id="color">
                    <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
                    <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
                    <option value="#FFCC00">Orange</option>
                    <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
                    <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
                    <option value="#663366">Indigo</option>
                    <option value="#FF00FF">Violet</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <input type="button" onClick="inputForm()" value="change color"/>
            <input type="button" onClick="storeColor()" value="save color"/>
            <script>
            var outputContents;
            function inputForm(){
                var color = document.getElementById("color");

                outputContents=color.value;

                document.body.style.backgroundColor = outputContents;
            }

            function storeColor(){
                // Store
                localStorage.color = outputContents;
                // Retrieve
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = outputContents;
            }
            </script>
        <form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or a session variable

Comment: @zoranc, otherDewi: Nonsense. Storing a value that is needed client-side only _on_ the client is a perfectly valid use case for localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage in JavaScript is uses (key, value) pairs of strings so if you wanted to save the  value `This is my test value.` you would need to give it a key that you can get it from later, for example `myTestValue`.

So in code this would be

`// set the value in window.localStorage`
`window.localStorage.setItem('myTestValue', 'This is my test value.')`

`// get the value from window.localStorage`
`window.localStorage.getItem('myTestValue')`

Here is some more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost complete. You only need to apply background color on window load. I added one more function `applyColor`:

```
function applyColor(color) {

    color = color || localStorage.color;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

    // Select corresponding option in selectbox
    var select = document.getElementById("color");
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        if (select.options[i].value == color) {
            select.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

applyColor();
```

Also note that when page is loaded we should also select the option from selectbox corresponding to currently saved color.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sd2Cx/